# Fragment - wait for onCreateView() to complete before running methods

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I'm struggling with a puzzling sequence of events relating to a `Fragment`. I'm trying to add a fragment to an `Activity`, and then call a method inside the fragment to update some text. However, what I am finding is that the method is being processed in the fragment *before* `onCreateView()` finishes, which leaves me with a null `View` object, and my method fails. Here is the `Activity` code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_entry_details);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    titleBarFragment = new TitleBarVerticalFragment();

    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.log_entry_title_frame, titleBarFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    titleBarFragment.updateTitleBar("Edit Log Entry", 20, false);
}
```

Seems simple enough. Here is the TitleBarVerticalFragment class:

```
public class TitleBarVerticalFragment extends TitleBarFragment {

    @Inject SharedVisualElements sharedVisualElements;

    View view;
    TextView titleLabel;

    public TitleBarVerticalFragment() {
        // add this line for any class that want to use any of the singleton objects
        Injector.INSTANCE.getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "title fragment onCreateView()");

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title_bar_vertical, container, false);

        ImageView logoImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logo_vertical);
        titleLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.verticalTitleLabel);

        titleLabel.setTextColor(sharedVisualElements.secondaryFontColor());
        titleLabel.setTypeface(sharedVisualElements.font());
        titleLabel.setTextSize(20);

        logoImage.setImageDrawable(sharedVisualElements.logoImage());
        logoImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        return view;
    }

    public void updateTitleBar(String text, int textSize, boolean titleLabelIsHidden) {

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "about to update title bar text");

        if (view == null) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "vertical title fragment is null");
            return;
        }

        if (titleLabel == null)
            titleLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.verticalTitleLabel);

        if (titleLabel == null) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "vertical title label is null");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "updating title text: " + text);
        titleLabel.setText(text);
        titleLabel.setTextSize(textSize);
    }
```

Note the order of this logcat output. Notice how `onCreateView()` seems to run *after* the `updateTitleBar()` method? How can that be?

> about to update title bar text
>  vertical title fragment is null
>   title fragment onCreateView()

How can I ensure that `onCreateView()` runs before I call any of the fragment's other methods? Thank you.

Comment: I usually use a `constructor` inside the `Fragment` to pass values into the `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks. I can also use setArguments, as well. This method already exists in the fragment class, so I was hoping to re-use it as is, rather than editing the class itself. I have other activities that already use this fragment, so I don't want to have to change them, too. I'm just curious why this runs out of order to learn a bit more about the fragment lifecycle.

Comment: Hi @Alex, can you post your solution? What did work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a listener interface and implement it in your Activity.

```
interface LyfecycleListener {
  void onCreatedView();
}
```

in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  this.titleBarFragment = new TitleBarVerticalFragment();
  this.titleBarFragment.setListener(this)
  ...
}

@Override
public void onCreatedView() {
  titleBarFragment.updateTitleBar("Edit Log Entry", 20, false);
}
```

in your Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

  this.listener.onCreatedView();
}
```

Comment: If I understand right, it seems that the code is self timing the events, rather than depending on Android to do so. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is a general solution for problem like this, called [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) .

Answer (score 6):

Try running fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() after fragmentTransaction.commit();  and before titleBarFragment.updateTitleBar("Edit Log Entry", 20, false);

Comment: That's a good idea. Didn't work for some reason, however. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `onStart()` on your activity